# Remove left margin from <a> tag on mobile with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend

I have some text wrapped in an 'a' tag with some margin-left. The margin-left helps separate it from a button that is directly to its left (on desktop/tablets). This works well for desktop/tablets, but on mobile, the 'a' tag moves right under the button, meaning there's no need for the margin-left anymore. How do I remove the margin for mobile users only? Or, more specifically, how do I remove the margin-left when the 'a' tag moves under the button? I've attached some screenshots of what I'm talking about and the code for the button and the 'a' tag.

Code for the 2 elements:

```
<div class="btn-group-one wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="500ms" data-wow-duration="1000ms">
    <a class="btn saasbox-btn white-btn mt-3" href="#">WEB APP</a>
    <a class="btn saasbox-btn-2 mt-3 ml-4" href="#">iOS &amp; Android Apps Coming Soon</a>
</div>
```

*Note: the mt-3, ml-4 and ml-4 'classes' come from Bootstrap. The 'ml-4' gives the element some 'rem' margin on the left.

MOBILE:

[image]

DESKTOP:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap margin classes have breakpoint-specific (ie screen width specific) options so you can set the margin for desktop only, eg `ml-md-4` where "md" is the medium screen width.  Depending on what breakpoint forces the `a` tag to wrap under the button you might have to choose "sm", "lg", etc.

Full documentation at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the width of your browser and register the width size in pixels when the tag moves under the button. For example it happened at 300px.

And add  class in your a tag for example mobilemargin and in your linked css file add the following

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
     .mobilemargin {
       margin-left: 0px;
     }
   }
```